# Enabled auto completion in notepad++ but how to see auto complete block irrespective of cases

Tags: notepad++

I have enabled auto complete feature in notepad++ for user defined language like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?>
<NotepadPlus>   
<!-- Go Programming Language  builtins and keywords -->
<AutoComplete>
<Environment ignoreCase="yes" startFunc="," stopFunc="," paramSeparator=","     terminal=";" additionalWordChar=""/>
<KeyWord name="abort"/>
<KeyWord name="Above"/>
</AutoComplete> 
</NotepadPlus>
```

Does autocomplete has this feature if i press "a" it should list down abort and Above in auto complete block or its always case sensitive?